# What is the list of Common Lisp functions on conses which are destructive?

Tags: common-lisp

I am reviewing some code which contains destructive operations on conses and I am hoping to find a list of all Common Lisp functions on conses which are destructive. I don't see such a list in the Common Lisp Hyper-Spec itself, and I wasn't able to find one via a web search.

This is presumably some subset of the functions listed by the CLHS under the heading "The Conses Dictionary", but I'm thinking I might miss something if I trawl through it myself, and also that there might be other functions which might modify a cons argument elsewhere in the CLHS.

I am mostly interested in functions which are allowed to be destructive, but not required. That includes stuff like NCONC and excludes RPLACA, for instance. I guess if there were a second list of functions on conses which are required to be destructive, that would be interesting and useful too.

Comment: you would also need to check the *Sequences* chapter.

Comment: `nconc` is required, not just allowed, to be destructive.  It's just that in some cases (a single argument, for instance), it is not.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Yes, well, it is exactly that exhaustive review which I am hoping, perhaps unreasonably, to avoid. Surely (I conjecture) this is something others have stumbled over in the long history of Common Lisp.

Comment: https://yoo2080.wordpress.com/2014/08/03/lisp-lists-and-destructive-functions/#sec-11

Comment: https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw61/CLHS/Body/03_ga.htm

Comment: If I was reviewing code, I can't see how I could meaningfully do so without knowing the language well enough to *know* if a given CL function was, or could be, destructive.  In the cases where I didn't, I'd use documentation lookup from the editor to find out.  Can you explain what your process, or proposed process, is?

Comment: Also https://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Issues/iss293_w.htm

Comment: @ignisvolens I dunno, man. I have to wonder what I have to do to prove my CL bona fides. FWIW I am looking over the function TIMESIN in simp.lisp (see https://sourceforge.net/p/maxima/code/ci/master/tree/src/) in search of a bug caused by an in-place modification. Maxima was originally written using a lot of destructive operations for the sake of efficiency, and especially in the core code, that has persisted to the present day. People currently working on the project scratch their heads and wonder what's going on. Towards that end the list of destructive functions could shed some light.

Comment: @coredump Thank you for the links, those are all helpful.

Comment: @RobertDodier I was not questioning your credentials: I merely don't understand how this would be useful.  Of functions which are explicitly destructive, `timesin` calls only `replaca`, `nconc` and `rplaced`.  But it uses `setf` which is destructive in combination with any accessor (I don't know how it uses it).  Likewise `incf`.

Answer (score 2):

Posting this as a community wiki:

- all `n`something functions: `nreverse`, `nsubstitute`… "n" means "non-consing", it doesn't need to allocate any new cons cell, it might reuse the original sequence.

  - `nstring-upcase`, `nstring-downcase`, `nstring-capitalize`
  - `nunion`, `nintersection`, `nset-difference`, `nset-exclusive-or`
  - `nbutlast`
  - `nsubst[-if, -if-not]`, `nsublis`,  `nsubstitue[-if, -if-not]`
- `sort`, `stable-sort`, `merge` (use `copy-list` or `copy-seq` before)
- `delete[-*]` functions (`remove` isn't destructive)
- `pop`, `push`
- `(setf (nth ... ...) ...)`
- `replace`, `fill`
- `vector-push` *can* be destructive
- `remprop`, `remf`
- `map-into`